# Loading url's in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have a UIViewController with a webView in it.

When tapping on a link, I would like to push a new controller and open the url in a new webview.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` ([docs here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:)), push your new controller and return `NO`.

I imagine that you've already got a handle on loading a URL into a WebView so I leave it at that.